# nginx with gzip for default route

Tags: php, nginx, gzip

I enabled gzip for nginx site:

```
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/html text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```

and while it works when I test it by executing: curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I http://domain/test.html:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 15:03:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=(CUT!); expires=Wed, 20-Feb-19 15:03:43 GMT; path=/; domain=..com; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 14:56:53 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: (CUT!)
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

,when I execute that curl for http://domain/ I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 15:05:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=(CUT!); expires=Wed, 20-Feb-19 15:05:57 GMT; path=/; domain=.(CUT!).com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: grav-site-(CUT!)=(CUT!); expires=Tue, 20-Feb-2018 15:35:57 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; domain=(CUT!).com
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: grav-site-(CUT!)=(CUT!); expires=Tue, 20-Feb-2018 15:35:57 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; domain=(CUT!).com; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Expires: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 15:05:57 GMT
Content-Encoding: none
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: (CUT!)
```

/ request is forwarded to fastcgi to handle php script..

What am I missing?

Comment: This seems to be coming from your cloudflare cache and may be that is why it is still not gzipped. Try `curl "http://domain/?_=4535454646"` and see what happens

Comment: I disabled cloudflare cache for now (development mode enabled + purged cache). Also, I think cloudflare cache would work the same for domain/ and domain/test.html

Comment: what is the size of the page? Can you also try directly on server using `http://127.0.0.1/`?

Comment: I tested with curl --resolve 'domain...com:80:serverip' - the same result, no cloudflare headers in response.